# Changing input audio source and setting it to mono on Debian Jessie/8 using commands

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, microphone

Good day everybody,
Today I was able to connect my WiiU to my computer using a PCI TV Tuner with a RCA  input, only yellow. Thanks to VLC and video4linux I can play games flawlessly. I bought a cable adapter to connect the red and white wires, from the RCA, to the microphone input. Then I run this command in order to hear audio:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

And run VLC:

```
vlc -vvv v4l2:// --v4l2-dev=/dev/video1 --v4l2-input=1 --v4l2-chroma=YUY2 --v4l2-width=720 --v4l2-height=576 --v4l2-aspect-ratio=16\:9 --v4l2-fps=25 --live-caching=1 --aspect-ratio 16\:9
```

Once I finish playing, I run this to disable Microphone listening:

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

Now my problem is: I have a Logitech webcam with microphone connected via USB, and this is my default microphone, and I have to go to System Preferences > Sound > Input and change the sound input device to Rear Microphone.
[image: My microphones]
Can I do this by commands? Yes, I need to run this command to switch to Rear Microphone:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

And this one to switch back to webcam microphone:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_0C629EC0-00-U0x46d0x823.iec958-stereo
```

I can see in input sources that the mic is switched, but the sound doesn't change, I keep listening the same sound source... if I do it by clicking on debian's preferences, it switches correctly. Am I missing something with those commands?
And what will I need in order to switch the Rear Microphone to mono? (Commands or a forever configuration) I have followed these instructions https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Remap_stereo_to_mono but I ended with no sound.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The OP post mentions changing the *input* to mono, but the other solution changes the *output* to mono.

To change the input to mono (this was necessary when I connected my mic to the Lexicon Alpha xlr input because by default the mic is recorded as stereo right only), you have to instead remap the *source* and not the *sink*:

List available sources:

```
pacmd list-sources | grep name:
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor>
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.3.iec958-stereo.monitor>
        name: <alsa_output.usb-Lexicon_Lexicon_Alpha-00.analog-stereo.monitor>
        name: <alsa_input.usb-Lexicon_Lexicon_Alpha-00.iec958-stereo>
```

In my case, the mic input source was `alsa_input.usb-Lexicon_Lexicon_Alpha-00.iec958-stereo`. So, we can create a new source, now with mono input. I named it `alpha_mono` but you can change that:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-source source_name=alpha_mono master=alsa_input.usb-Lexicon_Lexicon_Alpha-00.iec958-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

If desired, set new source as default (useful but not necessary):

```
pacmd set-default-source alpha_mono
```

Comment: If you don't have `pacmd`, try `pactl`. You can also use the verbose `pactl list sources` or the compact `pactl list short sources`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got everything by myself. Seems it's a bug, because there shouldn't be no application using the audio (neither playing to headphones nor recording from the mic) and I can run this command:

```
pacmd list-sources | grep alsa_input
```

Output:

```
name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
name: alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_0C629EC0-00-U0x46d0x823.iec958-stereo
name: alsa_input.pci-0000_08_00.0.analog-stereo
```

And running the following command changes the input source if no application is using the sound currently:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

To revert back to the webcam's microphone:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_0C629EC0-00-U0x46d0x823.iec958-stereo
```

Finally, the output as mono, same as above: Nothing using the audio sources and I run this command first:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

Output:

```
name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo
name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

And I run the command, choosing the analog-stereo:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

To revert:

```
pacmd unload-module module-remap-sink
```

Just wondering if using a 4.5 kernel from Jessie/Backports affects the audio output.

Comment: `sudo pacmd list-sinks | grep` name returns me: " No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon."

Comment: @Webwoman I don't know why, but running this command without sudo works.